# What to do when only parts of all answers add up to the solution?

Tags: discussion

I recently asked a question, then after a bit placed a bounty on it because I wanted to find a solution soon. Three people answered, the first didn't address the question but did bring up a couple points and offered a different way to accomplish the ultimate goal - if I had a different setup that might have worked for me. The next person who answered pointed out one specific problem in the code which had to be addressed, but this didn't answer the question. I commented, and the answerer replied to the comment with half of the solution to the problem - I upvoted that reply. The third person who answered basically explained the situation fairly well, but ultimately didn't quite answer the question. This answerer provided two suggestions, and the first one didn't help, but the latter one did although I did to use a different value than was suggested.

So I was ultimately able to completely resolve the issue using answer plus that answerer's comment, plus a tweaked suggestion offered in another answer. I feel that none of the answers are correct and deserving of the accepted answer/bounty. But I don't think it'd be right of me to put together their suggestions and answer my own question.

Do I wait to see if someone else answers with a full solution, do I comment on one of the answers and ask them to tweak theirs to more fully address the question, providing the solution I put together, or how would you handle this situation?

Comment: Why don't you add your own, complete, well-written answer that explains the solution in it's entirety and gives credit where it's due to the other answers. If you've had problems stitching other answers together someone will in the future too. Why not make it easy for them?

Comment: If you're that worried about the bounty situation, do it after the bounty expires.  Then there's no worries.